# Multiple users in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have two users in my app so I have built a custom user by subclassing `AbstractBaseUser` like this,

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()
    #other methods required here
```

and my users:

```
class User1(MyUser):
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(10),
                                 validators.MaxLengthValidator(10)])
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=Rename('user1_profiles'), null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    other_details = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class User2(MyUser):
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True, null=True, validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(10),
                                 validators.MaxLengthValidator(10)], unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=Rename('profiles'), null=True, blank=True,)
```

This works fine, but when I try to get user using `request.user` I get `MyUser` instance. In some API's I would like this to be `User1` and `User2` in other API's. To get this working I am using this in every API:

```
user = User1.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

or

```
user = User2.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this ? How can I stop User1 type users from accessing API's which are built for User2 type of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.user will always return MyUser instance.

Add the following attribute in MyUser -

```
 TYPES_OF_USERS = (("A", "USER1"), ("B", "USER2"))
 user_type = models.Charfield(max_length=1, choices=TYPES_OF_USERS)
```

Then, use this code

```
if request.user.user_type == "A":
      foo = request.user.User1.profile_pic
else:
      foo = request.user.User1.avatar
```

As an additional note- Since mobile is common to both models, store it in the main MyUser model.

Comment: Is there a better solution than using a a decorator on every view to grant access to correct user type?

Comment: You can use the permission mixin, though it won't make much of a difference.